# Flash AS3 - Problems Getting Flash to Load Dynamically Generated XML Files

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I'm not quite sure how to describe the problem I'm having but I'll do my best.

I have an image gallery built in AS3 that loads content via an XML file. Nothing mind blowing here...
When testing locally on a static XML file, the gallery works as intended.
The purpose of this gallery is to function within a CMS and load dynamically generated XML files to display the appropriate images/info for each particular gallery.

All this functions fine, to an extent...

The XML file that gets populated dynamically is called photos.xml.  This is what I am trying to load in the image gallery.

Once the XML file gets assigned to a specific gallery the string becomes something to the effect of photos.xml?content=xxxxxx

The only way I can get the gallery to function properly is if I tell the gallery to load that specific "photos.xml?content=xxxxxx" string, and it will, and everything works fine.

What I can't seem to get it to do is load a gallery, regardless of its specific string.  So if I'm at the index of all the galleries and I click on any of the galleries, it wont load the XML for that gallery.

So I guess what I'm asking is how can I get it so that the AS3 will load the XML for any gallery I click, whether is be "photos.xml?content=xxxxxx" or "photos.xml?content=yyyyyy" or "photos.xml?content=zzzzzz"

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can get the gallery to
>   function properly is if I tell the
>   gallery to load that specific
>   "photos.xml?content=xxxxxx" string,
>   and it will, and everything works
>   fine.

I looks like the cms is generating the xml file on request, in which case it's not the actionscript code that needs editing, but the backend/cms.

can you access the xml file without the `?content=xxxxxx` at the end? If not, that's the part you'll have to fix, or ad a call like `?content=showAll` and customize it to dump the entire structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the names ie xxx,yyy & zzz for example cant you simply call them something like:

"photos.xml?content="+ X[i];

where X could be an array of all the names you have.